# how to expand spinner time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to expand spinner time ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. This is totally unclear. Show some code. Explain some context. Are we expected to read your mind?

Answer (score 3):

From [The Nature of Time](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/A3577241):

> The Nature of Time
>
> We have all been asked the question
>   'what is the time?', but this entry
>   will be addressing the subtly
>   different question: 'what is time?'
>   Many people, on being asked this
>   question, would probably say that they
>   don't have the time to answer. In this
>   entry, we will explore many theories
>   about the nature of time. No one
>   theory has unquestioning truth about
>   it, so it will be up to you to decide
>   on the one you see is best.
>
> The Classical Approach to Time
>
> There is not very much to say on this
>   theory since it is the one with which
>   we are most familiar. Traditionally,
>   time is simply seen as a measure of
>   the distance between events. It has a
>   past, present and a future. The past
>   is considered to have already happened
>   and to be unchangeable, while the
>   future is considered to be open to
>   many possibilities. Humans measure
>   time using many units, some based on
>   real events like the rotation of the
>   Earth, others that are even more
>   arbitrary.
>
> Isaac Newton's classical description
>   of time in his highly-regarded work
>   Principia is that it 'flows equably of
>   itself', which means that time 'flows'
>   at a constant rate that is the same
>   for everybody - it is independent of
>   the events that take place in it. It
>   would be untrue to say that this idea
>   was unchallenged until the twentieth
>   century - the 18th-Century empiricist
>   philosopher George Berkeley, for
>   example, disagreed with Newton and
>   held that time was 'the succession of
>   ideas in the mind' - but there was no
>   serious evidence to suggest that
>   Newton's elegant and absolute
>   description was wrong until Einstein
>   destroyed it.
>
> Unfortunately, the classical view of
>   time is biased towards the human
>   perception of the 'flow' of time. We
>   see events in one direction, and we
>   assume time to be the same everywhere.
>   The classical approach to time does
>   not explain exactly why we perceive
>   time in this way, and it does not
>   describe how the effect is achieved.
>   The other theories of the nature of
>   time challenge the very roots of this
>   natural point of view.
>
> Relativity
>
> The Theory of Relativity is the
>   celebrated discovery of the physicist
>   Albert Einstein. Originally, it was
>   two theories: the Special Theory of
>   Relativity came first in 1905 and
>   states that the rate at which time
>   passes is not the same all over the
>   universe - it is dependent on the
>   observer (in other words, it is
>   relative). It is not hard to see that
>   different people perceive the passing
>   of time at a different rate to others:
>   as we get older, less information is
>   processed about our surroundings per
>   second, so we perceive time to be
>   going faster.
>
> But Einstein's theory went further
>   than this. The relativity of time is
>   based not on our age, but on our speed
>   of movement through space. The faster
>   we travel through space, the slower we
>   travel through time. Although this
>   sounds crazy at first, it makes sense
>   when thought of in a particular way.
>   The theory of relativity demands that
>   we view space and time not as separate
>   entities but as one concept called
>   space-time. Time becomes a fourth
>   dimension, just like the other three
>   dimensions of space that we are used
>   to (height, width and length). This
>   view of time is crucial to
>   understanding most of the other
>   theories about time's ultimate nature.
>
> Humans only possess two-dimensional
>   retinae (the light-receptive surface
>   at the back of our eyes), which means
>   that we can only see in two
>   dimensions. Our vision of the third
>   dimension is a result of perspective
>   and the existence of our binocular
>   vision. If we had three-dimensional
>   retinae, we would be able to see all
>   of an entire room simultaneously - its
>   walls, its floor and its ceiling at
>   the same time! For this reason, it is
>   very difficult, if not totally
>   impossible, for humans to visualise a
>   fourth dimension.
>
> To overcome this impairment, it is
>   useful to use lower-dimensional
>   analogies when talking about
>   dimensions above three, even if we are
>   talking about time as one of these
>   dimensions. So in this case, let us
>   imagine that the universe is shaped
>   like a cuboid1, and that humans are
>   two-dimensional and have
>   one-dimensional retinae. Imagine that
>   the spatial dimensions are the width
>   and height of a cross-section of the
>   cuboid, meaning that humans can move
>   up, down, left and right at will
>   within the cuboid. Imagine that the
>   depth of the cuboid is time.
>
> Right, now imagine that you are a
>   two-dimensional human within the
>   cuboid and that you start off being
>   midway up the cuboid. Then you start
>   moving upward (ie, through space, but
>   not time). Eventually you hit the edge
>   of the cuboid. Now imagine that you
>   move downwards, but that you also move
>   through time in a forward direction.
>   This time it will take you longer to
>   get back to being mid-way up the
>   cuboid because you are not taking a
>   direct route downwards - you are also
>   moving through time. As you can see,
>   moving through time slows down your
>   movement in space.
>
> It works the other way around too. If
>   you stay still in space and just move
>   forward in time, then it will take
>   less time to get to a particular point
>   in time than if you move upwards and
>   forwards in time simultaneously. So
>   movement in space slows down your
>   movement in time. This is what
>   relativity states about how time
>   really is. However, the amount by
>   which time is slowed down when you
>   move through space is very small in
>   everyday situations, and you would
>   need to move at a speed of a
>   considerable percentage the speed of
>   light in order for it to make any
>   noticeable difference.
>
> Relativity has been proven too. Atomic
>   clocks2 have been placed in aeroplanes
>   moving at high speeds and then
>   compared with clocks that were on
>   Earth. Slight differences that are
>   exactly predicted by the mathematical
>   equations of relativity were indeed
>   detected.
>
> The general theory of relativity goes
>   a step further and was published in
>   1916. Einstein stated that mass curves the 'fabric' of space-time to create
>   the illusion of the force of gravity.
>   Again, a lower-dimensional analogy is
>   best. Imagine putting bowling balls on
>   a sheet of rubber. They bend the
>   rubber. Any object coming into the
>   vicinity of the curve begins to move
>   around the curve like something
>   spiralling around a sink basin.
>   Einstein's picture of gravity is that
>   simple. And again, this has been
>   proved. Einstein made predictions
>   about how light would be taking
>   technically curved paths around large
>   masses, and this effect was measured
>   during a total eclipse of the sun.
>
> Time and Determinism
>
> You will have noticed that the theory
>   of relativity does not carry any
>   description of a 'flow' of time, and
>   in fact, it describes time in almost
>   exactly the same way that we are used
>   to thinking about space. Relativity
>   unifies space and time. All points in
>   space are in existence simultaneously
>   - this is common sense; so are all points in time in existence
>   simultaneously too? This would suggest
>   that all events in time are already
>   'here' and that there is no scope for
>   choosing what happens in the future.
>   This view of time is called
>   determinism because events are
>   pre-determined.
>
> It is worth noting that relativity
>   does not rule out the idea of free
>   will, but does not provide any support
>   for it either. Many people can get
>   upset about the evidence supporting
>   determinism because humans like to
>   think they have a free will to make
>   independent decisions. Such people
>   would not feel better if they heard
>   about the many worlds theory of
>   quantum mechanics.
>
> Time in the Many Worlds Theory of
>   Quantum Mechanics
>
> To understand this theory, we need to
>   go back to our cuboid example. You
>   will notice that each event in time is
>   simply a cross-section of the cuboid
>   (a square). Humans effectively
>   perceive the dimension of time in this
>   cuboid to be a succession of these
>   squares. Like frames in a movie, these
>   create the illusion of a smooth
>   passage of time. But why is it that we
>   see time like this? The answer to this
>   question will be explored later.
>
> If you think about the world around
>   you, you will most likely notice that
>   it seems to have been tailor-made for
>   life. The universe has the precise
>   properties that led to the formation
>   of life on Earth. For example, in the
>   early universe there was a 'battle'
>   between matter and anti-matter3. The
>   particles with the certain quantum
>   properties that we now characterise as
>   'matter', for a hitherto inexplicable
>   reason, won the battle. If this hadn't
>   happened, we could not exist, or we
>   would not be the same as we are today.
>   Many physicists have speculated that
>   this and other similar events are too
>   much of a coincidence to be regarded
>   as just that: a coincidence.
>
> Martin Rees, the Astronomer Royal of
>   the UK, paints an analogous picture of
>   going into a clothes shop. If you go
>   into a clothes shop that only sells
>   one size of clothing, it would be a
>   big coincidence if you found it was
>   your size. However, we get no surprise
>   when finding our own clothes size in a
>   clothes shop because good clothes
>   shops sell a wide range of clothes
>   sizes. We can now extend this picture
>   to the universe. It is very unlikely
>   that the universe should exist because
>   of how biased it seems to have been
>   towards gravitational stability and
>   the creation of diverse life later on.
>   However, if we see the universe as
>   providing a wide range of 'universes'
>   of different properties, it will come
>   as no surprise if we find one universe
>   that supports life.
>
> You can think of this theory as
>   multiple cuboids in a vast universe of
>   cuboids, all with their own
>   space-time. Each cuboid represents one
>   universe that has a different set of
>   laws of physics, and therefore could
>   be wildly different from all the other
>   universes. There may in fact be a
>   large number of universes that support
>   life but with small differences, just
>   as there might be many shirts of your
>   size in the clothes shop, but perhaps
>   in different colours.
>
> In this view, there are multiple
>   timelines. Some people have likened
>   this view of time to train tracks. We
>   move along a train track in one
>   direction, but there are huge numbers
>   of other train tracks running parallel
>   to ours. Each train track may be
>   different in some way (it might have
>   trains on it, for example). For this
>   reason, the other universes around us
>   in this 'multiverse'4 are referred to
>   as parallel universes.
>
> A multiverse of space-times is not
>   just a theory that solves the question
>   of why our environment is so suited to
>   life; it is also a theory of quantum
>   mechanics. In the quantum theory there
>   are many events that take place
>   because of random chance. In electric
>   currents, for example, the electrons
>   that make up the current follow a
>   random path in the wires that is
>   influenced by a fields of electrical
>   forces they pass through, which is why
>   it always seems that the current is
>   split 50:50. Many physicists believe
>   that with each quantum decision like
>   this, every possibility has a separate
>   universe in which it is enacted.
>   Hence, in one universe the electron
>   goes one way; in another, it goes the
>   other way.
>
> In this theory - which is called the
>   many worlds interpretation of quantum
>   mechanics - every possibility gets
>   enacted. Since quantum interactions
>   are the fundamentals of any larger (or
>   'macroscopic') reaction, we can infer
>   that everything happens in one
>   universe or other. So if you have a
>   decision to make, say whether to take
>   a holiday to Hawaii or not, there is
>   one universe where you go, and one
>   universe where you don't. This also
>   spells trouble for free will. All
>   possibilities get played out, so it is
>   just a matter of which universe you
>   are in to determine which way you go.
>
> There is a variation of this theory.
>   For this variation we will need to
>   think another dimension lower. So,
>   instead of imagining universes as
>   cuboids, we need to imagine them as
>   rectangles. Imagine the length of the
>   rectangle is time; and its other
>   dimension, space. The rectangle has no
>   thickness whatsoever, so if you put
>   multiple rectangles (ie, multiple
>   universes) on top of each other, the
>   whole structure becomes no thicker.
>   This version of the many worlds
>   interpretation is slightly easier to
>   grasp, because otherwise we would have
>   universes branching off from one
>   another to eternity, which is rather
>   difficult to imagine. There is no real
>   evidence for or against either of the
>   theories of the multiverse,
>   unfortunately.
>
> You will have noticed that in all
>   these theories, time has two
>   directions just like all the other
>   dimensions. In theory, there is
>   nothing to stop us from moving in the
>   other direction. There is another
>   slightly different theory of time as
>   being bi-directional, and you might
>   also be interested to see how this
>   could lead to possibilities of
>   time-travel.
>
> Why Do We Perceive Time the Way We Do?
>
> What, then, is time? If no one asks
>   me, I know what it is. If I wish to
>   explain it to him who asks me, I do
>   not know.
>   - St Augustine.  If time is a dimension just like all the others,
>   why do we experience it so
>   differently? This is the question that
>   interests James Hartle of the
>   University of California in Santa
>   Barbara, along with physicists Stephen
>   Hawking, Murray Gell-Mann and Steven
>   Weinberg. They believe that the
>   passage of time is just an illusion.
>
> Hartle thinks that time's arrow is a
>   product of the way we process
>   information. Gell-Mann gave creatures
>   that process time in this way the name
>   'information gathering and utilising
>   systems' (IGUSs). Humans are IGUSs.
>   Because of our two-dimensional
>   retinae, we can't take in multiple
>   cross-sections of the 'cuboid' - ie
>   'frames' of time - simultaneously. We
>   gather information about this frame -
>   our surrounding environment - using
>   our senses, and then we store the
>   information in an input register. This
>   does not have an unlimited capacity,
>   so we have to transfer the information
>   to our memory registers before we can
>   input the information about the next
>   frame. Humans have a short-term and a
>   long-term memory, as well as our
>   cerebellums that store 'unforgettable'
>   information (such as how to swim).
>
> IGUSs also carry something called a
>   'schema', which is a generalised model
>   of our perception of our environment.
>   It holds several rules about what is
>   best to do and what is not a good idea
>   to do. The information we receive from
>   our surroundings is passed to the
>   schema to determine how we react in
>   certain situations. The decision is
>   conscious, but we also do unconscious
>   computation of information: the schema
>   is updated unconsciously. The
>   conscious part of the IGUS in humans
>   focuses on the input register, which
>   we call the present. The unconscious
>   part focuses on information in the
>   memories, and we call that the past.
>   This is why we consciously experience
>   the present and remember the past.
>
> The movement of the information
>   through the IGUSs registers creates
>   the illusion of the flow of time. It
>   is not time itself that flows. Each
>   IGUS has a different speed for the
>   flow of its information between
>   registers. This corresponds to
>   differences between the perception of
>   the speed of the flow of time. Flies,
>   for example, need to process more
>   information per second in order to fly
>   so quickly but still avoid common
>   obstacles; therefore, they perceive
>   time as going slower. To us, a fly's
>   perception of time would look like
>   slow motion. Flies only live for a few
>   days, or a few weeks as a maximum, and
>   to a human, this is a very short
>   lifetime. But to a fly, this feels a
>   lot longer.
>
> So the reason that we experience a
>   'flow' of time could just be because
>   of how we process information. It is a
>   competitive advantage to us as a
>   species to process information bits at
>   a time. It wouldn't make sense for us
>   to have evolved with the capability to
>   see all time simultaneously.
>
> Digital Time, or, Is Time Like a
>   Movie?
>
> You may have noticed a reference to
>   'frames' of time in the explanations
>   above. We usually think of time as
>   continuous - a smooth passage of
>   events. However, most physical
>   theories define space and time as
>   being the opposite of a continuous
>   passage of events. M-theory and Loop
>   Quantum Gravity, for example, are both
>   serious scientific theories (not
>   proven theories, though) that state
>   that space and time have minimum
>   units. There was even a theory of
>   quantum mechanics to suggest that time
>   was made of particles called
>   'chronons'!
>
> The theorised minimum length of time
>   possible is called the Planck time and
>   is equivalent to 10-43 seconds. When
>   space or time is 'digital' like this,
>   we say that it is 'discrete'.
>
> If this theory is true, then our
>   perception of time could be like a
>   movie. Movies are not continuous: if
>   you slow them down enough, you see
>   that they are just collections of
>   still photographs played in quick
>   succession. We process information
>   about our surroundings and obtain a
>   picture just like one frame of a movie
>   or animation. When 'played' in quick
>   succession, this creates the illusion
>   of smooth, continuous movement.
>
> Is Time Really That Much Like Space?
>
> So far, time has been seen as very
>   much like a dimension of space, and
>   its passage in one direction has been
>   seen as an illusion. But there are
>   some counter-arguments; there are
>   still some big differences between
>   time and space that cannot easily be
>   explained as illusions.
>
> One way of supporting the idea that an
>   'arrow of time' is irrelevant is by
>   proving that all processes are the
>   same if done forwards or backwards. In
>   quantum mechanics, most interactions
>   between particles are 'time-symmetric'
>   - it doesn't matter whether you look at them from past to future or future
>   to past because they look the same.
>   But this is not true of macroscopic
>   objects. Wine glasses shatter, but you
>   rarely see shards of glass assemble
>   themselves into wine glasses.
>   Physicists can explain why shards of
>   glass do not form wine glasses by
>   postulating the existence of 'the
>   thermodynamic arrow of time'.
>
> Thermodynamics is basically a
>   collection of laws. Here is how the
>   chemist PW Atkins summarises them: 
>   There are four laws. The third of
>   them, the Second Law, was recognised
>   first; the first, the Zeroth law, was
>   formulated last; the First Law was
>   second; the Third Law might not even
>   be a law in the same sense as the
>   others. The gist of it is that the
>   universe is always becoming more
>   disordered. The disorder of the
>   universe is called 'entropy', so we
>   say that entropy is always increasing.
>   Nobody really knows why this is the
>   case, but we see it all the time in
>   experiments. This is why heat always
>   flows into colder areas, but never the
>   other way round. Heat is simply the
>   result of giving particles in a given
>   system more energy; they begin to move
>   and vibrate randomly, which is a
>   disordered state. Colder things are
>   more ordered because their constituent
>   particles tend to be harder to move.
>
> This in-built arrow explains why
>   macroscopic objects have irreversible
>   interactions. This is a clear
>   difference from space. If you think of
>   the spatial manifestation of a table,
>   it does not follow that one end of the
>   table is more disordered than the
>   other, but it does follow that the
>   table will end up more disordered in
>   the future than when it has just been
>   made. Hence, there is a very distinct
>   difference between time and space.
>
> Can Time Be Reversed?
>
> If time's 'flow' in one direction
>   really is an illusion, what is there
>   stopping us from reversing it? In
>   theory, nothing! Lawrence Schulman of
>   Clarkson University in New York
>   thoroughly believes that time can run
>   backwards. In other words, shards of
>   glass can turn into wine glasses,
>   people grow younger and younger and
>   the universe gets smaller and smaller.
>
> In fact, Schulman goes as far as to
>   say that such reversed-time zones can
>   exist as spaces within our own
>   universe. A computer simulation has
>   shown that regions with opposite time
>   arrows do not cancel each other out
>   and do not disturb each other at all.
>   The great thing about this theory is
>   that if a civilisation in a
>   reversed-time region kept records of
>   events that occur in our future, the
>   records might have survived to our
>   past (which is their future). Finding
>   these records could tell us the
>   future. This is, of course, a long
>   shot, but still a physical
>   possibility.
>
> Another possibility is that the
>   universe's arrow of time (as far as
>   thermodynamics is concerned) will
>   naturally reverse itself at a crucial
>   point in the history of the universe.
>   At this point, the universe would
>   start to get smaller and everybody
>   would get younger until there was a
>   big crunch analogous to the big bang.
>   This creates a perfect symmetry to the
>   universe.
>
> Again, there is little evidence that
>   shows us that reversed-time regions
>   exist, and there is no evidence that
>   the universe's thermodynamic arrow of
>   time will naturally reverse itself.
>   Equally, there is little evidence
>   against these theories either.
>
> So what is time? Is it a dimension
>   just like space? Does it flow, or is
>   that just an illusion? Is time digital
>   like the frames of a movie, or does it
>   flow continuously? And can time really
>   be reversed or manipulated? None of
>   these questions can be answered with
>   definite confidence, but next time
>   somebody asks you what the time is,
>   perhaps you'll think of the answer
>   differently.

Answer (score 0):

`Kernel::sleep` ?